# What can I do with "Syntax Templates" section at start of Symbol Pages (in Workbench)?

Tags: documentation, workbench

At the top of each Symbol Page, there are a bunch of little sections in grey (see screen shot).  But I do not understand how to use them.  I am particularly interested in the "Syntax templates" section.  How do I use it? Can it be used to override the the default template-generating algorithm from the `usage` inside the source files?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think those cells are used in any way in "ordinary" documentation.
There are no traces of anything from those cells in built notebooks, nor in any other file in deployed application.

If we search for strings, labeling those cells, in packages comming with workbench, we'll find them in `` DocumentationBuild`SystemResourcesFromDocs` `` package.
This package has some functions that can extract data, like usage cells, or syntax templates, from notebook, transform and write them to `*.m` files.
Functions mentioned above are used in `` DocumentationBuild`FunctionPaclets` `` package.

So it seems that cells from question are somehow related with something called *Function Paclets*.

Quoting comment from `` DocumentationBuild`FunctionPaclets` `` package:

> This file contains code for the task of processing the specialized author notebook for
>   single-function paclets into a standard paclet and auxiliary files. Paaclet building
>   includes creation of a PacletInfo.m file from metadata in the notebook, pulling the
>   implementation section out into a .m file, processing the docs into the standard in-product
>   format, and packing everything into a .paclet file. There is also functionality for
>   building a marketing page for the paclet and building HTML docs.
>   This code is called from a WRI server application when authors upload function paclet
>   notebooks. It can also be called on user machines to perform the processing steps locally.

It seems that `` DocumentationBuild`FunctionPaclets` `` package can build a `FunctionInformation.m` file mentioned in [answer to User-defined template; removing repeated text (v 9.0.1) question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40267#40325)

In `Window` > `Preferences` > `Mathematica` > `Paclet Development` there are two options: `Function Paclet Support` and `Function Paclet Infrastructure`, that can be checked.
They are labeled as experimental and I couldn't find anything about *Function Paclets* in worbench documentation.

If we switch on those experimental options we'll be able to check additional option `Full function paclet` in "application project" creation wizard.
In "function paclet application project" paclet editor has some additional buttons `Create/Install/Uninstall Paclet` and `Create Submission`, but I have not played with them yet.